# How do I keep the aside element from causing my website to have to scroll to the right

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make my website responsive for devices with a maximum width of 600px using CSS. Everything works fine except for my `aside` element. When I put my website in a responsiveness simulator, I can scroll to the right (which is not supposed to happen).

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/xirokif/pen/OJpjNWO

```css
/* https://codepen.io/xirokif/pen/zYZdqNg */

aside {
  float: right;
  width: 540px;
  background-color: #404653;
  border: 3px solid #30353f;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  aside {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  aside,
  li {
    padding: -3px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  aside,
  p {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  aside,
  summary {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 3px;
  }
  aside,
  details {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  hr {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}


/* table styling */

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3d4452;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HTML Forms</h1>
  <hr />
  <main>
    <details>
      <summary>HTML Forms</summary>
      <p>An HTML form is used to collect user input, and is most often sent to a server for processing.</p>
    </details>
  </main>
  <hr />
</header>
<!-- Page content section -->
<section>
  <!-- Elements section -->
  <section>
    <!-- Aside element -->
    <section>
      <aside>
        <div>
          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Form tags</p>
          <details>
            <summary>Elements</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>form</li>
              <li>input</li>
              <li>label</li>
              <li>input</li>
            </ul>
          </details>
          <details>
            <summary>Attributes</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>text</li>
              <li>radio</li>
              <li>checkbox</li>
              <li>submit</li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </section>
    <!-- Form element -->
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>form</code> element</h2>
      <p>The element is used to create an HTML form for user input</p>
      <p>The elment is a container for different types of input elements, such as text fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, submit buttons, etc.</p>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <!-- Input element -->
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>input</code> element</h2>
      <p><code>input</code> is the most used form element</p>
      <p>The element can be displated in many ways, depending on the <code>type</code> attribute.</p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>Displays a single-line text input field</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>radio</td>
            <td>Displays a radio button (for selecting one of many choices)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>checkbox</td>
            <td>Displays a checkbox (for selecting zero or more of many choices)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>submit</td>
            <td>Displays a submit button (for submitting the form</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>button</td>
            <td>Displays a clickable button</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>label</code> Element</h2>
      <p>The <code>label</code> tag defines a label for many form elements.</p>
      <p>The <code>for</code> attribute of the <code>label</code> tag should be equal to the <code>id</code> attribute of the <code>input</code> element to put them together.</p>
      <p class="note"><b>Note</b> - It is useful for screen-reader users because the screen-reader will read the label out loud when the user focuses on the input element.</p>
      <hr>
    </section>
  </section>
  <!-- input attributes section -->
  <section>
    <!-- Text Fields -->
    <section>
      <h2>Text Fields</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a single-line input field for text input.
      </p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-1.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a radio button.
      </p>
      <p>Radio buttons let a user select <strong>ONE</strong> of a limited number of choices.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-2.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr />
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Checkboxes</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a checkbox.
      </p>
      <p>Checkboxes let a user select <b>ZERO</b> or <b>MORE</b> options of a limited number of choices.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-3.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr />
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The Submit Button</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a button for submitting the form data to a form-handler.
      </p>
      <p>The form-handler is typically a file on the server with a script for processing input data.</p>
      <p>The form-handler is specified in the form's <code>action</code> attribute.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-4.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The Name Attribute for <code>input</code></h2>
      <p>Each input field must have a <code>name</code> attribute to be submitted.</p>
      <p>If the <code>name</code> attribute is omitted, the value of the input field will not be sent at all.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

The image one the top is normal the one on the bottom shows the scroll
[image: Normal]
[image: Abnormal]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hans is correct.  The negative margin appears to be causing the overflow.  Also, note that `padding: -3px` is invalid.  [Negative values for padding properties are invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-box-3/#padding-physical)

Comment: [Look again](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67712127/revisions).

Comment: @isherwood there are no red highlights which means that nothing was removed. Just green highlighted code that was added (by me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative margin on the `aside` element causes the overall body width to exceed 100%. That is why a scroll bar is shown by browsers.

Remove the line `margin-right: -15px;` in the declaration for the `aside` element and the scrollbar should be gone.

```css
aside {
  float: right;
  width: 540px;
  background-color: #404653;
  border: 3px solid #30353f;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  aside {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  aside,
  li {
    padding: -3px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  aside,
  p {
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  aside,
  summary {
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 3px;
  }
  aside,
  details {
    /* margin-right: -15px; This line must be gone! */
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  p {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  hr {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  a {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}


/* table styling */

table,
th,
td {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #3d4452;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>HTML Forms</h1>
  <hr />
  <main>
    <details>
      <summary>HTML Forms</summary>
      <p>An HTML form is used to collect user input, and is most often sent to a server for processing.</p>
    </details>
  </main>
  <hr />
</header>
<!-- Page content section -->
<section>
  <!-- Elements section -->
  <section>
    <!-- Aside element -->
    <section>
      <aside>
        <div>
          <p style="font-size: 15px;">Form tags</p>
          <details>
            <summary>Elements</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>form</li>
              <li>input</li>
              <li>label</li>
              <li>input</li>
            </ul>
          </details>
          <details>
            <summary>Attributes</summary>
            <ul>
              <li>text</li>
              <li>radio</li>
              <li>checkbox</li>
              <li>submit</li>
            </ul>
          </details>
        </div>
      </aside>
    </section>
    <!-- Form element -->
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>form</code> element</h2>
      <p>The element is used to create an HTML form for user input</p>
      <p>The elment is a container for different types of input elements, such as text fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, submit buttons, etc.</p>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <!-- Input element -->
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>input</code> element</h2>
      <p><code>input</code> is the most used form element</p>
      <p>The element can be displated in many ways, depending on the <code>type</code> attribute.</p>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>Displays a single-line text input field</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>radio</td>
            <td>Displays a radio button (for selecting one of many choices)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>checkbox</td>
            <td>Displays a checkbox (for selecting zero or more of many choices)</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>submit</td>
            <td>Displays a submit button (for submitting the form</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>button</td>
            <td>Displays a clickable button</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The <code>label</code> Element</h2>
      <p>The <code>label</code> tag defines a label for many form elements.</p>
      <p>The <code>for</code> attribute of the <code>label</code> tag should be equal to the <code>id</code> attribute of the <code>input</code> element to put them together.</p>
      <p class="note"><b>Note</b> - It is useful for screen-reader users because the screen-reader will read the label out loud when the user focuses on the input element.</p>
      <hr>
    </section>
  </section>
  <!-- input attributes section -->
  <section>
    <!-- Text Fields -->
    <section>
      <h2>Text Fields</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a single-line input field for text input.
      </p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-1.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Radio Buttons</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a radio button.
      </p>
      <p>Radio buttons let a user select <strong>ONE</strong> of a limited number of choices.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-2.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr />
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>Checkboxes</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a checkbox.
      </p>
      <p>Checkboxes let a user select <b>ZERO</b> or <b>MORE</b> options of a limited number of choices.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-3.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr />
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The Submit Button</h2>
      <p>The
        <!-- Insert code block here -->defines a button for submitting the form data to a form-handler.
      </p>
      <p>The form-handler is typically a file on the server with a script for processing input data.</p>
      <p>The form-handler is specified in the form's <code>action</code> attribute.</p>
      <a href="html-forms-example-4.html" target="_blank">Example Here</a>
      <hr>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h2>The Name Attribute for <code>input</code></h2>
      <p>Each input field must have a <code>name</code> attribute to be submitted.</p>
      <p>If the <code>name</code> attribute is omitted, the value of the input field will not be sent at all.</p>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```